# Detaching part of feature without detaching all parts from each other?

Tags: qgis, merge, features, splitting, multipart

On this map, Denmark and Greenland are one feature, and I need them to be two features. How do I split them apart?

If I use Singlepart to Multipart, I create a new layer where there is a feature for each island (denmark has a lot of islands).

Is there a way I can specify that only Greenland as a whole gets split up?

[image: Europe]

Comment: `"Multipart to singleparts"` in the Processing Toolbox,  and then `"Dissolve"` (selected all Denmark's parts without Greenland).

Comment: Otherwise select Denmark + Greenland and apply `"Split Features"` (or `"Split Parts"`) from Advanced Digitizing Toolbar.