# Part of feature belongs to wrong feature

Tags: qgis, merge, splitting, multipart, singlepart

Is there a quick way (without having to create new layers) to make the island circled in the bottom left a part of central america (dark blue) rather than a -part of Central France (yellow)?

[image: picture]

Comment: Check my comments in this thread [Detaching part of feature without detaching all parts from each other?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371214/detaching-part-of-feature-without-detaching-all-parts-from-each-other).

Comment: Note it is part of France!

Comment: I know it's part of France, but this map is more about some specific airport zones.

Comment: @Taras I tried that, but it creates a new layer, and if I then have to put it back to the layer after doing the correct merges, I would have to delete the parts. It's very messy. Can't I just select the part of the feature that needs to be a new feature?

Comment: Can you provide an access to the data? For instance here https://tapiquen-sig.jimdofree.com/english-version/free-downloads/world/ your issue was solved by the default.

Comment: Check this thread also [How to Split Features in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46862/how-to-split-features-in-qgis)

Comment: I think the split features only works for one polygon. I wish I could cut between to separate parts and it would work. The data is protected unfortunately.